# Mixing White Paint into Ceiling Knockdown Mud

Tags: ceiling

I would like to knockdown a ceiling (newbie) and read that it is desirable to add **white paint** to drywall mud.  It seems reasonable that it would be preferable to have the color 'built-in' to the mud so that it never needs painting.  I do not know the color of drywall mud, but it would seem that it is not quite white

This is the desired outcome:

[image]

Is there a 'recipe' that provides for the amounts of water, paint, etc?

Bonus round: Is there a rule of thumb for estimating paint / drywall mud based on ceiling area to be covered?

Edits to this post that sharpen the question is appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have added paint to mud with mixed results. The mud dilutes the paint color making it hard to match areas that are not sprayed. I have had good luck adding primer to mudd that appeared to reduce the ussage of primer before painting but probably the total amount of primer was about the same. 1 note of caution. With straight mud overspray is really easy to clean when paint is added now cleanup of overspray is a bear. Calculating the amount of mud is hard to guess because we don't know if you want orange peal (a light texture) or a heavy plaster knock down look (heavy texture). Drywall mud usually drys chalk white, much like the center between the paper.

Comment: I added a picture of the knockdown outcome that I am seeking to the posting.  Not sure if it is 'heavy texture'?   Thanks for the 'note of caution': good stuff

Comment: With trying to match the photo I would use a gun with the large orifice and set the gun to open the plunger all the way if you have both settings this will provide the larger globs to knockdown. The best advice is to test shoot and adjust your gun for the desired amount if you don't have a large scrap of sheetrock to test you can shoot it and scrape it off if it is not the look you are after.

Comment: @EdBeal +1 For acknowledging cleanup with paint added is more difficult.